# generate data table of "coxph" object in a similar way as for "survfit" object

Tags: r, cox-regression, survival-analysis

When I use `summary()` for a `survfit` object, I get a nice data.frame with columns for

```
time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
```

But `summary()` on a `coxph` object gives a different result. I realize functions work differently on different object classes, but is there a command that works on `coxph` in a similar way that `summary()` works on `survfit`? I haven't been able to find answers so far in the documentation.

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't extract the formula from the cox model and use it to construct a survfit object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on @BenBarnes comment.

You can pass a `coxph` object (the result of fitting the model) to the `survfit` function and it will return the information similar to using survfit directly.  By default it will give a single table (or plotted line if you plot the result) corresponding to all the covariates at their mean, but you can also give it a `newdata` data frame with the covariate values you want to use and it will give you a table (plotted line) for each row of the data frame.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much Ben and Greg.